# how can a matrix vector product reduce to a scalar?

Tags: linear-algebra, numerical-linear-algebra

I have an Excel spreadsheet with the following formula (paraphrased):

```
=MMULT(  MMULT(vector_as_n_column_matrix, n_by_n_square_matrix)  
        ,TRANSPOSE(vector_as_n_column_matrix)
      )
```

the matrix and vector contain floating point values.  Excel evaluates this formula as a scalar.  I don't recall matrix math working that way.  However, it's been over 30 years since I studies linear algebra.

Does it make sense that the result should be a scalar?  Can you explain why in terms of linear algebra?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Multiplying an $m\times n$ matrix on the right by an $n\times p$ matrix yields an $m\times p$ matrix. You have
$$v^t Av$$
which is a $1\times n$ matrix times an $n\times n$ matrix times an $n\times 1$ matrix. The result is a $1\times 1$ matrix.

Answer (score 3):

working from right to left  : A $n\times n$ matrix times a $1 \times n$ vector yields a $1 \times n$ vector (given that they are of the same size). Your first $1\times n$  vector times this resultant vector yields a scalar [via the dot product] (again pending that the two vectors have the same dimension), so yes your answer makes sense .

Answer (score 1):

Just to expand on what's already been said, given an $n\times n$ matrix $A\in M_{n\times n}(K)$, you can define the map $f:K^n\rightarrow K$ by $f_A(v)=v^\intercal A v$.  These types of map are called [bilinear forms](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bilinear_form) (closely related: [quadratic forms](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadratic_form)).  Bilinear forms appear all over mathematics.

Comment: Thanks.  I found the link on bilinear forms to be an interesting read.